# Read Elements from file using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

If I have a file with name "read7" with a list of numbers in it, for example:

```
2
3
4
```

How can I write a bash script with a while loop to read all the elements in the file and square the numbers and send it as a standard output?

So, after running the script we should get an output of

```
4
9
16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `while` loop, you could say:

```
while read -r i; do echo $((i*i)); done < read7
```

For your input, it'd emit:

```
4
9
16
```

---

As per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323527/read-elements-from-file-using-bash-script/20323599?noredirect=1#comment30330727_20323599), `if the file has words and numbers in it. How do I make it read just the numbers from the file?`.  You could say:

```
while read -r i; do [[ $i == [0-9]* ]] && echo $((i*i)); done < read7
```

For an input file containing:

```
2
foo
3
4
```

it'd produce:

```
4
9
16
```

Comment: I missed out a point in my question, if the file has words and numbers in it. How do I make it read just the numbers from the file?

Answer (score 2):

Try awk:

```
awk '{print $1*$1}' read7
```

Comment: yeah, however, I would like to do it with a while loop. will it be possible with a while loop?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `while` loop. Using `awk`:

```
$ cat read7
2
3
4
$ awk '{print $1*$1}' read7
4
9
16
```

Comment: I would like to do it with a while loop. will it be possible with a while loop?

Comment: @anansharm, `while read n; do bc <<< $n*$n ; done < read7` or `while read n; do echo $((n*n)) ; done < read7` as devnull's answer.